# getting started with programming Arduino board in C/embedded c

Tags: avrdude

I want to move away from Arduino IDE and start directly working with avrdude. Can anyone tell me some resources and tips on starting and moving forward with using C/embedded C to access more functionality.Would appreciate some help.

Comment: The Atmel/Microchip web site may be a place to start for AVR development.

Comment: Read the chip datasheet. It has everything you need.

Comment: Check out Atmel Studio 7.

Answer (score 2):

Not an exhaustive answer, but one step would be to realize what the Arduino IDE does behind the scenes before it gives your source code to `avr-gcc`.

From https://github.com/arduino/arduino/wiki/build-process#pre-processing

> The Arduino environment performs a few transformations to your sketch
>   before passing it to the `avr-gcc` compiler:
>
> - All `.ino` files in the sketch folder (shown in the IDE as tabs with no    extension) are concatenated together, starting with the
>     file that    matches the folder name followed by the others in
>     alphabetical order,    and the `.cpp` extension is added to the
>     filename.
> - If not already    present, `#include <Arduino.h>` is added to the sketch. This header    file (found in the core folder for the
>     currently selected board)    includes all the definitions needed for
>     the standard Arduino core.
> - Prototypes are generated for all function definitions in `.ino` files    that don't already have prototypes. In some rare cases
>     prototype    generation may fail for some functions. To work around
>     this, you can    provide your own prototypes for these functions.
> - `#line` directives are added to make warning or error messages reflect the original sketch layout.
>
> No pre-processing is done to files in a sketch with any extension
>   other than `.ino`. Additionally, `.h` files in the sketch are not
>   automatically `#include`d from the main sketch file. Further, if you
>   want to call functions defined in a `.c` file from a `.cpp` file (like
>   one generated from your sketch), you'll need to wrap its declarations
>   in an `extern "C" {}` block that is defined only inside of C++ files.

This is handy to know if you are trying to *port* Arduino sketches to pure `avr-gcc`.

You'll also want to have the header files that define all the various registers specific to the ATMega328p that is the heart of several of the Arduino boards. They can be downloaded as part of [Atmel Studio 7](http://www.microchip.com/mplab/avr-support/atmel-studio-7), which also includes `avr-gcc` and the various other toolchain utilities and scripts necessary.

You'll also want the processor's reference manual or datasheet. At this time, the data sheet is available at https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATmega328P in the "Documents" tab. This will lay out **everything** you ever need to know about how to use the processor, set up peripherals, rules for the order of commands, names of all the registers, etc.